# Add/Subtract cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cells, subtraction

In my app, I have a `UITableView` with 3 cells.  If the user selects one of the top two cells, they can change the value using a `UIDatePicker` to make it say for example "November 11, 2011".

Is there a way to subtract the dates from the first cell to the second one?

Like the user inputs "November 11, 2011" into the first cell, and in the second cell inputs "November 11, 2012", how can I get the 3rd cell to say, "1", or "1 year"?

My code is -

.h

```
IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    UITableView *products;
    NSMutableArray *productsInfo, *extras;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *products;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;;
-(IBAction)DateChanged:(id)sender;
```

.m -

```
@implementation PushedViewController

@synthesize datePicker;
@synthesize products,dateFormatter;

-(IBAction)DateChanged:(id)sender{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.products indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.products cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    productsInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    extras = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [extras addObject:@"Time Left"];
    [productsInfo addObject:@"Date Bought"];
    [productsInfo addObject:@"Date Ending"];

    //product.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MakeText"];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (section==0){
        return [productsInfo count];
    }
    else{
        return [extras count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if (indexPath.section==0){
        cell.textLabel.text = [productsInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Time Left";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"8";
    }


    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *targetCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you will have to store each of those two dates selected in the cells in instance variable to reference in the third cell.  After the third cell has both dates that it needs to perform the calculation, things get a little more difficult.  Using two `NSDate`s, you are wanting to output a time interval in human words to the user.  There are not any factory methods for doing this, but a friend of mine has created a helpful class, [`TTTTimeIntervalFormatter`](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit) that will do just this.

You can use it like so:

```
NSDate *dateFromFirstDatePicker = [datePicker1 date];
NSDate *dateFromSecondDatePicker = [datePicker2 date];
TTTTimeIntervalFormatter *timeIntervalFormatter = [[TTTTimeIntervalFormatter alloc] init];

NSString *timeInterval = [timeIntervalFormatter stringForTimeInterval:[dateFromFirstDatePicker timeIntervalSinceDate:dateFromSecondDatePicker]];

//other examples
[timeIntervalFormatter stringForTimeInterval:0]; // "just now"
[timeIntervalFormatter stringForTimeInterval:100]; // "1 minute ago"
[timeIntervalFormatter stringForTimeInterval:8000]; // "2 hours ago"

[timeIntervalFormatter release];
```

Then you can update the third cell using the standard `UITableViewDataSource` method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to update the contents of the cell.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do but the thing is that I don't have 2 UIDatePickers, Only 1. I'll update my code to show you, it is in the original post.

By the way, thanks for all your help

Comment: Ok that doesn't really change my answer.  You will simply need to store the date after the user selects a date from the picker depending on the cell selected.  Doesn't matter if you only use a single date picker or not - simply store the date in the appropriate instance variable so you can do the calculation on the third cell when you have two dates.

Comment: How can I declare the NSDates accordingly with the cell at the row?

Comment: When the user clicks on a row, have it display a date picker.  When the user is finished entering the date, store the `NSDate` from the `UIDatePicker` using `[UIDatePicker date]` in an instance variable named `date1` or something.  Do the same for the second date.  When both dates are stored, then simply call the third cell with the code above to get the time interval.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it in the:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if([indexPath row] == 1){
      // Get the date from the cell:
      UITableViewCell *cell=[table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      // Take care of the date
      // (...)
      // Give it to the other cells:
      UITableViewCell *cell=[table cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]]; // this is a reference to the second cell in the table (I assume you have 3: 0,1,2)
    }
}
```

And then do what you want with your cell.

Comment: I see what you're saying but how can I subtract the cells and put that date into the third cell while keeping the same date format?